# $\oint_{\Gamma}^{} (x^{\frac{4}{3}}+y^{\frac{4}{3}})ds,\Gamma \text{ is } x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=a^{\frac{2}{3}}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

$\oint_{\Gamma}^{} (x^{\frac{4}{3}}+y^{\frac{4}{3}})ds,\Gamma \text{ is } x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=a^{\frac{2}{3}}$
my process is below

$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
  x=r\text{cos}\theta \\  
  y=r\text{sin}\theta 
\end{matrix}\right. 
\ \theta \in [0,2\pi]$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$I=a^\frac{4}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^4\theta+\sin^4\theta)3a\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$3a^\frac{7}{3}\left(-\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^5d(\cos\theta)+\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^5d(\sin\theta)\right)$$
it is zero, but the answer is $4a^\frac{7}{3}$
The answer uses symmetry to limit the range between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Why is my answer wrong and should use symmetry to limit the range first?

And what kind of problem should I limit the range first?

Comment: Why did you take the parametrization of the circle? That curve is called astroid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20astroid%20is,with%20four%20times%20the%20radius.

Comment: Yes, this problem can also be solved without parametrization, thank you

Comment: So you solved it?

Comment: yeah, but I still don't know why my other solution is incorrect

Comment: I don't remember line integarl much but please tell me if I'm incorrect. You're writing $\int_{\Gamma}f(x,y)\,ds=\int_0^{2\pi}f(a\cos^3t,a\sin^3t) \sqrt{\frac{dx}{dt}^2+\frac{dy}{dt}^2}\,dt$, right? Then the $3a\cos\theta\sin\theta$ term will be $3a|\cos\theta||\sin\theta|$. So may be the terms will not cancel and you'll not get $0$.

Comment: yeah! you're right, I forgot to keep the absolute value。 thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142862/discussion-between-liyushu-and-pndas).

Comment: Take advantage of symmetry. Instead of integrating over $[0,2\pi]$, multiply the integral over $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ by $4$.